# Debian live USB has no EFI boot driver and cannot be installed on an Acer laptop

Tags: debian, live-usb, uefi, laptop, acer

I have created two live USBs in two separate pendrives:

- The first one has an ISO image of Debian.
- The second one has an ISO image of Fedora.

### Equal conditions

- My laptop: Aspire V11 Touch (aka V3 112P P2E7)
- My boot manager: InsydeH2O Setup Utility Rev 5.0
- Commands to create the live-USB:

  - create gtp partition table
  - format to fat32 filesystem
  - `dd if=path-to-iso-source of=/dev/sdX`

This seems to be in line with what I consulted in the Debian documentation, namely [3.6.3. Systems with UEFI firmware](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s06.html.en#UEFI) and [4.3. Preparing Files for USB Memory Stick Booting](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-isohybrid).

### Aim

To bootstrap the laptop with a live version of Debian or Fedora by using the respective pendrive.

### Issue description

- The boot loader does not even recognize that a stick is plugged into the port with the Debian image. Hence no booting from it.
- With Fedora, no problem.

### Settings proven not to be relevant

- UEFI/Legacy mode
- Secure/Not Secure boot

Although the suggestion to downgrade these options seems to be almost commonplace, my issue is independent of those.

- Fedora works well with the standard settings (UEFI + Secure Mode)
- Debian does not work with any combination allowed by the boot loader.

See [this post on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1029708/boot-manager-in-laptop-does-not-recognise-bootable-pendrive) for early explorations of this problem.

### First diagnosis

Therefore I came to the conclusion that the problem resides in the ISO images. Below I compare their directory trees of them. I suspect that the Debian image lacks an EFI directory that Fedora has.

### Working: Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso

Source [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD)

Directory tree:

`<path to USB>
 ├── EFI
 │   └── BOOT
 ├── isolinux
 └── LiveOS`

### Not working: debian-live-8.2.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso

Source [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)

Directory tree:

`<path to USB>
 ├── debian -> .
 ├── dists
 │   ├── jessie
 │   ├── stable -> jessie
 │   ├── testing -> jessie
 │   └── unstable -> jessie
 ├── install
 │   └── gtk
 ├── isolinux
 ├── live
 ├── pool
 │   └── main
 └── tools`

### Questions

Was my attempt ill-fated because I picked an inappropriate Debian ISO image from the repository? If so, could you please point me in the direction of guidelines on which one to choose?

How can I create a Debian ISO image that has the same capabilities as the Fedora one?

This problem will be sorted out when the boot loader

- recognizes that a memory stick is in place;
- accepts booting from that memory stick.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: try this maybe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382817/uefi-bios-bootable-live-debian-stretch-amd64-with-persistence

Comment: @vizzy Thanks for the tip; in the meantime I had given up with installing Debian and stayed with Ubuntu. Hopefully, this post can be fruitful in the future, for me reviewing the issue and anyone else approaching it.